# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object laravel7.7

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Hello everyone i'm using prefixing in routes for localization and i have a problem in the id of  show and edit method when i make dd($id); or echo  i found it as a prefix "en" or "fr" can someone help me

[image]

this is the route

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{language?}'], function(){

    Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome');});
    Route::resource('application', 'ApplicationController');
    Route::resource('appkey', 'AppKeyController');
    Route::get('/export', 'ApplicationController@export')->name('export');
    Route::get('/exportkey', 'AppKeyController@export')->name('exportkey');

});

Route::get('/{any}', function() {
    $locale = app()->getLocale();
    if( !$locale ) {
        $locale = config('app.fallback_locale');
    }
    dd( '/' . $locale . request()->path() );
    return redirect( '/' . $locale . request()->path() );
})->where('any', '.*');
```

```
    public function show($id)
        {
            $key = AppKey::find($id);
            return view('pages.keys.show') -> with('key', $key);
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
        {  
            $app = Application::pluck('name', 'app_id');
            $key = AppKey::find($id);
            dd($id);
            return view('pages.keys.edit', compact('app')) -> with('key', $key);

        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the relevant code and route

Comment: @kerbholz i did

Comment: `property 'id' of non-object` usually stems from `$something->id`, and there's no `->id` in any of your code here. So your error is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried using `edit(Request $request, $id)`? Also, do you get `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object` or the language, seems contradictory

Comment: @kerbholz yes i did still the same error